# Python SSL Bad Handshake

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, curl, python-requests

I'm having a very particular problem.
In particular, I'd like to retrieve the content of the following website:  `https://www.mycardtamoil.it/`

As I understood, this website has some issues with the SSL certificate. If you open it in Chrome, you have no issue, but if you try to retrieve the content via cURL (`curl https://www.mycardtamoil.it/`) you receive an error on ssl that can bypass using the option `-k`

When I move to Python3, I'm not able to bypass this issue; the code I've tested is:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.mycardtamoil.it/', verify=False)
```

but I get the following expection:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- SysCallError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py
>   in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
>   suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
>       440             try:
>   --> 441                 cnx.do_handshake()
>       442             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in
>   do_handshake(self)    1906         result =
>   _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
>   -> 1907         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)    1908
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in
>   _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)    1631                         raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
>   -> 1632                 raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")    1633             else:
>
> SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
>   in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
>   body_pos, **response_kw)
>       600                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
>   --> 601                                                   chunked=chunked)
>       602
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
>   in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked,
>   **httplib_request_kw)
>       345         try:
>   --> 346             self._validate_conn(conn)
>       347         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
>   in _validate_conn(self, conn)
>       849         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
>   --> 850             conn.connect()
>       851
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in
>   connect(self)
>       325             server_hostname=hostname,
>   --> 326             ssl_context=context)
>       327
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in
>   ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs,
>   server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
>       328     if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
>   --> 329         return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
>       330
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py
>   in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
>   suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
>       447             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
>   --> 448                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
>       449             break
>
> SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py
>   in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       439                     retries=self.max_retries,
>   --> 440                     timeout=timeout
>       441                 )
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py
>   in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
>   body_pos, **response_kw)
>       638             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
>   --> 639                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>       640             retries.sleep()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in
>   increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
>       387         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
>   --> 388             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>       389
>
> MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.mycardtamoil.it',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected
>   EOF')",),))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import requests
>   ----> 2 response = requests.get('https://www.mycardtamoil.it/', verify=False)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url,
>   params, **kwargs)
>        70 
>        71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
>   ---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>        73 
>        74
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in
>   request(method, url, **kwargs)
>        56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
>        57     with sessions.Session() as session:
>   ---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>        59 
>        60
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in
>   request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files,
>   auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert,
>   json)
>       506         }
>       507         send_kwargs.update(settings)
>   --> 508         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>       509 
>       510         return resp
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in
>   send(self, request, **kwargs)
>       616 
>       617         # Send the request
>   --> 618         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>       619 
>       620         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in
>   send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       504             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
>       505                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
>   --> 506                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>       507 
>       508             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>
> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.mycardtamoil.it', port=443):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad
>   handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",),))

Can someone help me to understand how I can fix it using requests module?

Thanks in advance,
Salvo

Comment: you end your string with a backslash. Escape the backslash. `a = '\'` will give an error. `a='\\'` is okay

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using forward slash that don't require escape. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.mycardtamoil.it) the server has a terrible setup. Notably it only supports TLS 1.0 and less (even the more or less broken SSLv3 and the absolutely broken SSLv2) and it also only supports ciphers which are considered weak or really insecure.

While clients usually support TLS 1.0 (still considered sufficiently secure despite known problems) they usually don't support weak and insecure ciphers - at least by default but sometimes they are not even compiled in any longer. Probably the less insecure cipher supported by the server is TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (called DES-CBC3-SHA within OpenSSL).

Assuming that this cipher is still available in the version of OpenSSL used by your Python you could hack requests into enable this cipher. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141655/requests-failing-to-connect-to-a-tls-server) this could be done like this:

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
requests.get('https://www.mycardtamoil.it/')
```

While it now no longer gets a `Unexpected EOF` it gets another error: `certificate verify failed`. This is because the servers setup is not only broken regarding protocol versions and ciphers but also the certificate is not properly configured. The [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.mycardtamoil.it) shows among all the other problems also

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete.

Adding `verify=False` like you did "fixes" the problem by adding even more insecurity, i.e. it skips the validation of the certificate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538930/ssl-error-with-python-requests-despite-up-to-date-dependencies) for how such situations can be properly fixed. Although, it is not clear if properly checking the certificate would actually significantly improve the security in this situation where you have to deal with a severely broken and insecure system. I recommend to not sent any sensitive data to this system, no matter if HTTPS is used or not.

Comment: Thank you, for your very clear explanation. Now it works.
As you highlighted, this server configuration is very unsecure. I'll avoid to send any sensitive data as you suggested

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I wrote 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DES-CBC3-SHA' ' this code in mine. But I get error **no chiper match**. How can I make default again?

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: I have no real idea of what you are trying to do. Explicitly overriding the default ciphers should only be done if needed since the relevant cipher is not in there. If you want to use the default ciphers from Python simple don't override the default ciphers.

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: I have no real idea of what you are trying to do. Explicitly overriding the default ciphers should only be done if needed since the relevant cipher is not in there. If you want to use the default ciphers from Python simple don't override the default ciphers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I solved it with this code: 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL' '

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: This is not "solved". This is worked around with a seemingly working code which  has the problem of allowing also terrible insecure ciphers.  Note that when dealing with security it does not mean it is secure if it just works.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this is solution my situation. It turn default with this code. Also, about SSL error I get this error when I run in office and I didn't get in home. I think the problem was with internet connection.

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: if you use this work around for things which don't matter anyway (i.e. where you need no security) then it is fine. In all other cases please don't do it this way.