# Python Request API works in postman and does not work in python (Bad HandShake)

Tags: python, api, ssl, get, request

My code:

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url = 'https://104.41.29.106/apibasic/linkdados/v1/qtlink?funcionalidade=RELATORIO&selecao=Fundos%20MM%20Macro%20e%20LS&configuracao=Fundos%20MM%20Macro%20e%20LS'

headers = {'user-agent': 'customize header string', 'Content-Type': 'application/gzip; charset=utf-8'}

r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx'), headers=headers, verify=False)
print(r.text)

Error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='104.41.29.106', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /apibasic/linkdados/v1/qtlink?funcionalidade=RELATORIO&selecao=Fundos%20MM%20Macro%20e%20LS&configuracao=Fundos%20MM%20Macro%20e%20LS (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",),))

Comment: your code and postman are in the same PC?

Comment: Yes. They are in the same PC

Comment: And if i call the API by Browser,it works too.

Comment: check this , is about "bad handshake"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158229/python-ssl-bad-handshake

Comment: I add verify=False in code, but still doesn´t working